# sending a form using phpmailer with google SMTP

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I have a free user account on freehostia.com with SMTP off. I have a contact form in my site which I wish to mail on my email after submit. as SMTP off I wish to use phpmailer to acomplish this with google SMTP service. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "SMTP off". Do you mean they block outbound SMTP? or that there is no local mail server so you can't use PHP's `mail()` function?

Assuming the latter, look at [the examples that are provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).

Comment: SMTP off means: they blocked outgoing mail. When I attempt to send a mail an error "SMTP error" occurred.

Comment: This makes no sense. You're saying you want to use SMTP with PHPMailer, but they are blocking SMTP, so you can't. It's your ISP that needs fixing. Aside from that, look at the examples and read the docs.